# How to create and open a new serial comport in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've been trying to connect to physical comport from just two other applications.

It's a rs-232 serial communication port.
Now, I've used a hardware splitter for this, but I wanna develop this with my software application.

I wrote some code with C#. As you guys know, there is excellent package named System.IO.Ports.SerialPort in C# already.

but you know, this package can only open ports that exist already. I wanna create a 'new comport'

I've been looking for proper solutions. so I've already seen [com0com](https://github.com/paulakg4/com0com) and [VSPE from eterlogic](http://www.eterlogic.com/Downloads.html) and [VPSD from eltima](https://www.virtual-serial-port.org/vspd-comparison-chart.html).

It's so awesome apps. but I should put this functions in my application.

For example, "A" application own specific real port 'COM10'. 
I wanna make connect to 'COM10' port, not only "B" application from "A" application.

My plan is I'll write the program which makes two 'Virtual port'. let's say "a", "b". 
Two different applications will be connected "a", "b" virtual ports. and those ports are connected to "COM10".

In conclusion I wanna connect the two program to just one real port with two virtual port.

So my question is that there is any way to create and open a new comport programmatically by any chance.

please I'll wait response from experts.

Comment: A serial port is in Device Manager and you must add the serial port to device manager and have a driver associated with the device.  You  can only open a deivde that EXISTS so first you have to locate the hardware associated with  port and add to Device Manager.

Comment: so I wanna know how to create virtual port. I saw that's possible from the applications that i mentioned.

Comment: Maybe, you could use pinvoke but it depends on your use case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301786.aspx

Comment: The virtual port GITHUB is making a connection between two applications which looks looks a serial port.  No hardware.  A serial Port uses Hardware and installs the hardware in device manager.  How are you defining "Virtual Hardware"?

Comment: First of all THANKS FOR YOU GUYS' REPLY. @jdweng "Virtual Port" is literally not a real port but it's kind of a port that can be connected from applications and .
For example, "A" application own specific real port 'COM10'. I wanna make connect to 'COM10' port, not only "B" application from "A" application.
My plan is I'll write the program which makes two 'Virtual port'. let's say "a", "b". Two different applications will be connected "a", "b" virtual port. and those ports are connected to "COM10". In conclusion I wanna connect the two program to just one real port with two virtual port.

Comment: You should use TCP to make connection(s) and just make you application look like a serial port.

Comment: I figured out that I should develop on driver level with wdk(window driver kit)

I hope this will be helpful for you guys.
[msdn driver development](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows-hardware/drivers/),
[sample codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/samples/serial-driver-samples)